# Filter table using a list of dates

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a table with many rows,  first column is a date. I want to filter these dates based on another list of dates. Whenever I run my code,  it deselects everything as if I had no matches even though I copy pasted a sample of the data in my list.

First, I checked if dates have the same format in both lists.
Format is typed in like this `mm/dd/yyyy` but it shows as `09 Jun 2019`

Second,  I tried to filter using only one date instead of the entire list.

Third, I tried ungrouping the dates in the drop down filter.

I also tried different operators for the range of dates: `Operator:=xlOr` and 
                                                         `Operator:=xlAnd`

```
'Ungroup dates in filter
ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping = Not ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping

'Filter for one date
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau_TxtDateCahiersGI").Range("$A$1:$F$4124").AutoFilterie ld:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dates").Range("A2")

'Filter for range of dates     
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau_TxtDateCahiersGI").Range("$A$1:$F$4124").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dates").Range("A2:A7"), Operator:=xlOr
```

I expect the code to filter the table based on the other list.

```
Example :
Table 1 :            List :              Result :
28 Mar 19            28 Mar 19           28 Mar 19 
10 Jun 19            07 Jun 19           09 Apr 19
01 Apr 19            09 Apr 19           09 Apr 19
09 Apr 19            09 Apr 19           16 Apr 19
09 Apr 19            16 Apr 19           16 Apr 19
10 Apr 19            16 Apr 19
16 Apr 19
16 Apr 19
```

Comment: Can you edit your question in the Right Format! I spent 5 mins to format and you undid all the changes.

Comment: I am sorry,  didn't know you were changing it, my first time asking a question on here

Comment: No worries, Just edit it so that anyone can read it and understand what you are asking. At the moment it looks very messy

Comment: @Mikku rolled it back for ya

Answer (score 0):

The desired list is in sheet Dates in column A. We will make an array (**ary**) from this list:

```
Sub FilterDate()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range
With Sheets("Dates")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim ary(1 To N)
        For i = 1 To N
            ary(i) = .Cells(i, 1)
        Next i
End With

    Range("A1:F4124").AutoFilter
    Sheets("Tableau_TxtDateCahiersGI").Range("$A$1:$F$4124").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: did not work,  this removed the filter I had in place

Comment: @Chayeboob This don't filter with your list of date as criteria  ?

Comment: Nope this removed the filter,  but data is still as is

Comment: @Chayeboob Lets do an other way and pass your list as an array, please give the new code a try.